# Why does this callback function not add bind.(this)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I know, we need to use .bind each time when you pass your custom function to an event handler like onChange or onSubmit

In the following Example ,we pass an event handler (talk function) as a prop.
When a user click a button,talk function will be called.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Button = require('./Button');

var Talker = React.createClass({
  talk: function () {
    for (var speech = '', i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      speech += 'blah ';
    }
    alert(speech);
  },

  render: function () {
    return <Button talk={this.talk}/>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Talker />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Button.js

```
var React = require('react');

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.talk}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Button;
```

This example uses Button talk={this.talk} instead of Button {this.talk.bind.(this)}
,but why?

Comment: You only need `.bind` if you need `this` inside the function to refer to a specific value. Since `talk` doesn't access `this`, `.bind` isn't necessary. There is also the fact that `React.createClass` autobinds each method, but that doesn't make a difference in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind` is used to ensure the function is called with the context of the class rather than the context of the caller.

It is required particularly when you access class properties within the function.
For example if your `speech` variable was a class variable rather than a local one.

```
talk: function () {
    for (this.speech = '', i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      this.speech += 'blah ';
    }
    alert(this.speech);
  },
```

In this case you would need `bind`.

Your `talk` function is not doing this.
It has its own local variables and so can be called using any `this` context.

`talk={this.talk}` will work here.

Also the syntax for bind function incorrect in the question. It needs to be `this.talk.bind(this)` not `this.talk.bind.(this)`

Comment: I think all  answers here all correct but this explanation is much easier for others  to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected when using `createClass` where React binds every method (custom and that of React component API) to their component resulting 'this' to be available. same cannot be said about when using ES6 `.... extends React.Component` where react only binds 'this' to react component API methods.

Also, you don't exactly need to do this.talk.bind(this) each time were you using ES6 in your render method, instead

you could

```
constructor () {
    super()
    this.talk = this.talk.bind(this)
}
```

and use this.talk() anywhere in it.

for in-depth explanation, https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-create-class-vs-es6-class-components/

Comment: interesting.. although you got the syntax wrong..it needs to be `this.talk.bind(this)`. You added an extra `.` there.

Answer (score 0):

Because, basically, .bind will "bind" a particular object to "this". But since the function doesn't make a use of "this" so it won't be matter if you bind it or not.

if in the function talk you have reference to a "Talker" class's instance. that's the moment you will start getting some issues.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to use `bind` if the component `Talker` is used in another component. If it is the case, `this` in the `Talker` component would refer to the other component instead. In your current case, it is passed down to the button. Therefore, the use of `bind` is required to ensure that it is calling from `Talker` instead of the `Button` component.